# How to use optimizer.minimize with maxPooling layers in TensorFlow.js

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow.js

When using `optimizer.minimize()` with `model.predict()` to train a model with a loss function in TensorFlow.js, I encounter an issue. This only occurs when I use a `maxPooling2D` layer in a convolutional neural network with code similar to the code below. It produces this error: `Cannot read property 'backend' of undefined`. I'm not sure what is causing this or how to resolve it. The error does not occur when using a convolutional layer (`tf.layers.conv2d()`) without any pooling layers. I'm using TensorFlow.js version `0.14.2` and Google Chrome version `71.0.3578.98`. This error can be reproduced using the following code:

```
loss = (pred, label) => pred.sub(label).square().mean();
optimizer = tf.train.sgd(0.001);

const input = tf.input({shape: [100, 100, 4]});
const conv = tf.layers.conv2d({
    kernelSize: 5,
    filters: 8,
    strides: 1,
    activation: 'relu',
    kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling'
});
const pool = tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
    poolSize: [2, 2],
    strides: [2, 2]
});
const flat = tf.layers.flatten();
const dense = tf.layers.dense({units: 10});
const output = dense.apply(flat.apply(pool.apply(conv.apply(input))));
const model = tf.model({inputs: input, outputs: output});

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    optimizer.minimize(() =>
        loss(model.predict([tf.ones([1, 100, 100, 4])]), tf.ones([1, 10]))
    );
}
```

Edit: This has been resolved. See [scai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54496577/10940584) for details.

Edit 2: This appears to not be a bug, but a change to backpropagation with `model.predict()`. [More information](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1189#issuecomment-459990915)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TensorFlow.js 0.14+, there is a change that disables backpropagation support in the Model.predict() method. You can use the Model.apply() method with the {training: true} flag to fix your code.

I.e., change

```
    optimizer.minimize(() =>
    loss(model.predict([tf.ones([1, 100, 100, 4])]), tf.ones([1, 10]))
);
```

to

```
   optimizer.minimize(() =>
    loss(model.apply([tf.ones([1, 100, 100, 4])], {training: true}), tf.ones([1, 10]))
);
```